# Design pattern for making asynchronous call method to go synchronous way in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, design-patterns, asynchronous, python-unittest

I am writing test cases for a socket program. The socket will accept messages in a thread asynchronously. I need to write a test case which will validate a specific message. From my test case I should call waitFor(x, timeout) which will wait for specific message. The waitFor() function should be synchronous.

What design patterns exist that can be used for this situation?

Comment: listener-subscriber maybe ? I forget what its actually called ... (of coarse observer design pattern) ... maybe your question isn't simply what the name of the design pattern is ...

Comment: Thanks Joran, but I wanted know how I can apply this to a testcase which will make my thread asyncronous